# Foreign key is not saving in @OneToMany relation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

```
public class ReadLesson {        
    private int index;     

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "read_lesson_id")
    private LessonIntrod introduction;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "readlesson", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<LesImage> images;

//getter n setters

}

public class LesImage {

    @Column(name = "imageid")
    private int imageid;

    @Column(name = "image")
    private String image;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "readlesson_id", nullable = false)
    private ReadLesson readlesson;

}
```

Comment: Please post the way you set the data.

Comment: Sorry i didnt get your question. I'm using JSON to pass the data in postman

Comment: Could you please share your JSON object?